# UninitializedPropertyAccessException : lateinit property encodedCredentials has not been initialized while writing a unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I got stuck in an scenario where I am unable to get pass above exception while writing unit test of some existing files. Below is my code:

```
class LoginViewModel(
private val loginUseCase: LoginUseCase,
private val baseEncoder: BaseEncoder,
private val preferenceManager: PreferenceManager
) : ViewModel(), LoginCallback {

private lateinit var encodedCredentials: String

private val _loginEvents = LiveEvent<LoginEvent>()
val loginEvents: LiveData<LoginEvent> get() = _loginEvents

init {
        loginUseCase.setCallback(this)
    }

override fun onLoginResult(result: Result) {
when (result) {
            Result.Success -> {
                saveCredentialsForBiometricsSetUp()
                _loginEvents.value = NavigateToSuccess
            }
Result.GenericError -> _loginEvents.value = GenericError
}
}

fun login(username: String, password: String) {
  baseEncoder.encode(username, password, prefix = BASIC_KEY).also {
                loginUseCase.execute(it)
                encodedCredentials = it
            }
}

private fun saveCredentialsForBiometricsSetUp() {
        preferenceManager.encodedCredentials = encodedCredentials
    }
}
```

Above is my LoginViewModel class, Also LoginEvent is sealed class with some events.

I write below unit test class and observing error in that test case,

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class LoginViewModelTest {

@Mock
private lateinit var mockBaseEncoder: BaseEncoder

@Mock
private lateinit var mockPreferenceManager: PreferenceManager

@Mock
private lateinit var mockLoginUseCase: LoginUseCase

 @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel


@Test
    fun `navigate to Accounts list when login state as Success`() {
        // GIVEN
        val loginStateResult = LoginUseCase.Result.Success
        val userName = "userName"
        val password = "password"
        val encodedCredentials = "encoded_string"

        whenever(mockBaseEncoder.encode(userName, password, BASIC_KEY)).thenReturn(encodedCredentials)

        // WHEN login API been called & login result received
        viewModel.login(userName, password)
        viewModel.onLoginResult(loginStateResult)

        // AND when loginEvent state is observed
        val loginEventObserver = viewModel.loginEvents.test()

        // THEN
        loginEventObserver.assertValue{
            it is LoginEvent.NavigateToSuccess
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting **UninitializedPropertyAccessException : lateinit property encodedCredentials has not been initialized** while writing a unit test

Main cause of it is encodedCredentials is not getting initialized, as it getting initilise in login() function only, but in also{} block. My problem is I am not able to get this initiated.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? This started all of a sudden with latest IDE updates to Arctic Fox

Comment: Unfortunately not, I changed the implementation at my end.